# MySQL - как хранить ключевые слова (теги) к посту блога?

Tags: php, mysql

Такая проблема

При добавлении поста в блог, можно будет вводить ключевые слова (точно так же как тут)

Ключевые слова будут храниться в отдельной таблице

```
id | ключевое слово | md5 ключевого слова
```

Обратите внимание на md5 ключевого слова, этоя сделал чтобы быстрее сверять есть ключевое слово в базе или еще нет, правильное решение пришло мне на ум или есть кто умнее что изобрел?

Ну да ладно

Вторая таблица такая

```
id | заголовок | сообщение | ключевые слова | id юзера
```

Главный вопрос в том как хранить запись ключевые слова

Целесообразно ли допустим хранить в таком формате с разделителем

```
id1;id5;id9
```

где id это из первой таблицы номера

или же нужно создавать третью таблицу для связки?

```
id слова | id поста
```

В общем народу будет дофига, нужно чтобы это не грузило базу, как лучше сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всего будет три таблицы: **`prfx_posts, prfx_tags, prfx_posts_tags`**

В таблице prfx_tags храним id тега и его название. Это будет таблица со списком возможных тегов.

В таблице prfx_posts_tags храним id поста и id тега соответствущего посту. Здесь может быть несколько тегов для оного поста, то бишь для одного `post_id` может быть несколько `tag_id` вида:

```
|  post_id  |  tag_id  |
|        1  |       3  |
|        1  |       5  |
|        1  |       7  |
```

tag_id это внешний ключ для таблицы `prfx_tags`, `post_id` - для `prfx_posts_tags`.

Структура - **prfx_tags**:

```
|  tag_id  |  tag_name  |
```

Структура - **prfx_posts**:

```
|  post_id  |  title  | message  |  user_id  |
```

Структура - **`prfx_posts_tags`**:

```
| post_id  | tag_id  |
```

**По поводу оптимизации:**

1. Выбираем тип таблицы или MyISAM или
       InnoDB, InnoDB хорош тем, что есть
       обновление / удаление записей по ключам в
       данном случае, но он тормоз из-за
       транзакций и т.д. Берём MyISAM.
2. Создаём индексы для колонок.
3. Аккуратно выбираем типы клонок.
4. Аккуратно выбираем длинну полей.

**По поводу логику:**

При добавлении поста в БД пользователю должны предлагаться теги из таблицы `prfx_tags`
Когда он добавляет пост данные заносятся в две таблицы: в `prfx_posts` и в `prfx_posts_tags`
В `prfx_posts_tags` летит id поста в колонку `post_id` и id тега в `tag_id`

Откуда брать теги? Либо самому создать базу тегов, либо ещё и дать возможность пользователю их добавлять в `prfx_tags` без повторений, второе сложнее =)

**И на последок:**

1. Нужно следить за ссылочной целостностью в БД. Так как при
       удалении тега в таблице `prfx_tags`
       остаются ссылки / записи на него в
       таблице `prfx_posts_tags` - их так
       же нужно удалять.
2. Нужно ли объяснить SQL запрос на
       выборку?

Это всё.

Comment: @GenchiK, всё в общем-то не плохо, но то, что "*самому создать базу тегов*" оказывается легче, чем "*дать возможность пользователю их добавлять*", для меня было открытием ;) Хотя, если учитывать, что эта база будет состоять из 30-50 тегов, и юзер не найдя нужного, будет лепить "что попало", то такой вариант, естественно, что имеет место быть.

Comment: спасибо за детальный ответ

интересует какой тип ключей устанавливать и для каких значений

(с id понятно - там всегда примари кей)

Comment: Я дополню свой коментарий. Если вы собирётесь давать пользователю возможность добавлять теги самостоятельно, что в общем правильно, то в таблице (как у @GenchiK) **prfx_tags**, поле **tag_name** делаете уникальным ключиком. В этом случае, если пользователь пытается добавить существующий тег, мы страхуемся таким запросом:

    INSERT IGNORE INTO `prfx_tags` (`tag_name`) VALUES ('GenchiK')

Comment: @Deonis, я просто подумал о малом кол-ве =) А так Вы всё по делу написали =)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону [serialize](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php)